# How to put an EDIT control in a custom popup window using Win32 API?

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to add an EDIT control to a window used as a dropdown for a custom combobox-like control. Initially this dropdown window was implemented as a child (`WS_CHILD`) window of the desktop, which is similar to the "ComboLbox" window used by the real combobox. This worked just fine, however an EDIT window seems to just refuse to accept focus when it is put into such dropdown window. I.e. it is enabled and reacts to right mouse clicks, for example, but clicking on it or calling `SetFocus()` fails (the latter sets last error to `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`).

Because of this, and also because of the way custom popup windows are implemented in many examples including Raymond Chen's [fakemenu sample](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040820-00/?p=38103), I've changed the dropdown implementation to use `WS_POPUP`, with the main application window as owner. This has a known problem with stealing activation from the owner window when the popup is shown, however this can be addressed by returning `MA_NOACTIVATE` from `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` handler for the popup window and it indeed works well initially, i.e. the owner window keeps activation when the popup shows up. But as soon as I click the EDIT control inside the popup, it calls, from its default window proc, `SetFocus()` to set the focus to itself, which deactivates the parent window.

My question is how can I prevent this from happening? I know that it can be done because WinForms [ToolStripManager](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolStripManager.cs) manages to allow editing text in a dropdown without deactivating the parent window and it also uses `WS_POPUP` style for the popup window. But how does it do it?

Comment: I believe you can prevent the host window from visibly appearing inactive by handling `WM_NCACTIVATE`, and returning `FALSE` when `wParam == FALSE`. Alternatively, you could try making the popup window be owned by the parent window.

Comment: Unfortunately returning `FALSE` from `WM_NCACTIVATE` prevents `SetFocus()` from working, apparently, i.e. it becomes impossible to give focus to the EDIT inside the popup if I do this. Also, the popup _is_ already owned by the parent window, but not setting any owner actually doesn't seem to change anything anyhow.

Comment: Have you tried returning `MA_NOACTIVATE` from `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` handler of the edit control too?

Comment: @zett42 No, thanks for the idea. But unfortunately after doing it right now, I see that it doesn't change anything (I'm actually surprised, I thought it would prevent the EDIT from getting focus), i.e. the EDIT still gets focus and the parent/owner window loses activation. Returning `MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT` does prevent it from happening, but then the EDIT is not usable (e.g. doesn't show the caret nor selection).

Comment: You have to forward the relevant messages from the modal loop directly to the edit control like in the fake menu example. That should at least allow the text to be editable. For the caret/selection issue you could have a look at [`EM_TAKEFOCUS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-takefocus) and [`EM_NOSETFOCUS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-nosetfocus). From the docs of `EM_TAKEFOCUS`: _"If the edit control previously received an EM_NOSETFOCUS message, the edit control will appear to have the focus without actually having it"_

Comment: Wow, these messages appear to be a well-guarded secret: I had never heard about them and there are almost no matches when searching for them. But yes, they should allow me to do what I need, thanks! Please move this to an answer so that I could accept it. Of course, this is rather hackish and I hoped for something that would work with any control (and this one really works *only* with single line EDITs), but this is still very helpful, thanks!

Comment: I have not validated my findings, so I suggest that you just answer your own question once you have implemented a succesful solution. Cheers!

Comment: I looked at the *"fakemenu"* example and it has too many issues for it to have a child window. There is a call to `SetCapture/ReleaseCapture` and a message loop to intercept all mouse and keyboard inputs. The child window of the popup will not receive any mouse/keyboard messages, and this can't be easily tweaked. I am not sure what your own routine does.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I don't actually use the code from "fakemenu", I just looked at it for inspiration. In particular, I don't even have a modal loop (I'm not sure why is it needed, it looks like I can just close the popup whenever it loses focus -- at least this used to work without problems with the child window approach). Right now I just have a very small WinAPI program I use as a testbed which doesn't even dismiss the popup, but it already shows the issues with the EDIT control.

Comment: This can be done easily in c# with a `contextMenuStrip` and adding a `textbox` to it but in win32 it is a different story. The moral is you can do it, the problem is how.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε Well, yes, this is exactly what this question is about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution was suggested in comments *"prevent the host window from visibly appearing inactive by handling `WM_NCACTIVATE`"* This should work as shown in the example below.

When menu window is opened, the host window (`HostProc`) will receive `WM_NCACTIVATE` message. Host will look for `"menuclass"`, if menu class is found then host will return `DefWindowProc(hwnd, WM_NCACTIVATE, TRUE, lparam);` to prevent the title bar for host window get painted inactive.

You also need to handle `WM_NCACTIVATE` in fake menu window. When menu window goes out of focus, `WM_NCACTIVATE` is received by `MenuProc`, at this point the menu can close itself.

```
#include <windows.h>

const wchar_t* menuclass = L"menuclass";

LRESULT CALLBACK MenuProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindow(L"Edit", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 10, 10, 160, 30,
            hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        break;

    case WM_NCACTIVATE:
    {
        if(!wparam)
        {
            //close the menu if its losing focus
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);

            //tell parent to paint inactive, if user clicked on a different program
            POINT pt;
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            HWND hit = WindowFromPoint(pt);
            HWND hparent = GetParent(hwnd);
            if(hit != hparent && !IsChild(hparent, hit))
                DefWindowProc(hparent, WM_NCACTIVATE, FALSE, 0);
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
        break;
    //also handles other mouse/key messages associated with a menu...
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK HostProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_NCACTIVATE:
        //paint the window as active when custom menu starts
        if(!wparam && FindWindow(menuclass, NULL))
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, WM_NCACTIVATE, TRUE, lparam);
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
    {
        //show the custom menu
        POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        CreateWindow(menuclass, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER,
            pt.x, pt.y, 200, 400, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = HostProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"hostwnd";
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    wcex.lpfnWndProc = MenuProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = menuclass;
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    CreateWindow(L"hostwnd", L"Right click for menu ...", 
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 600, 400, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I've finally implemented this approach in my real code and it seems to work fine, except that I also had to explicitly send `WM_NCACTIVATE` with `FALSE` when losing activation in the popup window as otherwise switching to another application dismissed the popup but continued showing the owning window as being active, which looked wrong. This is just a detail, of course, but if anybody else reuses this code, keep this in mind.