# What is the best way to create custom menu with WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, menu, controls

Since there is no way to deep customizing (a gradient background for example) win32 controls (such as buttons, menu items e.t.c) many people advise to create an own custom control.

And if I need a custom button I will use WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN and a shadow buffer. I will draw all controls on the shadow buffer and then use BitBlt(hDC, ...) for my window.

But if I want to create a custom menu I must to foresee that menu can be drawn outside of the client area.
At first I need to mouse tracking outside of the client area. SetCapture(hWnd) seems to be a bad solution as it blocks mouse tracking for windows below.
Then I need to draw/erase items outside of my window. Erasing with InvalidateRect(NULL, NULL, TRUE/FALSE)  seems to be a bad solution too as it cause of blinking.

What is the best approach to create custom menu with WinAPI?

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52808753/4603670)

Answer (score 0):

Runtime menus that can appear anywhere on the screen can be shown with [TrackPopupMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu)() function. Create the menu with CreateMenu(), AppendMenu() etc, then show it with TrackPopupMenu().

Comment: But how can I draw totaly custom menu item (for example item with gradient background)?

Comment: @Arseniy You either use MF_OWNERDRAW and WM_MEASUREITEM/WM_DRAWITEM to draw it manually, or you use some library like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1493/A-Powerful-Ownerdraw-Menu). Suggestion: Windows users and developers hate inconsistency in GUIs, this is not linux. When some new Windows changes the default theme, your app will be outdated, not to mention the maintenance burden for such a simple thing as a menu. Stick to the standards.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use MF_OWNERDRAW / WM_MEASUREITEM / WM_DRAWITEM.
But. Executable example of this library is not working on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: @Arseniy that is exactly what is going to happen to *your* code as well when you unfollow the standards.